# How to get width without scrollbar size with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

When I use $window.innerHeight it is returning the size counting the scrollbar size. I'd like to know how to get it without the scrollbar size.

Answer (score 0):

`window.innerHeight` always return the inner height of a window.

Please read [window.innerHeight Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)

`$window.innerHeight` will throw a reference error. Please remove `$` from it.